# How can i generate a listbox algorithm?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have 2 textboxes for my list box.

1. start number and
2. finish number

I typing numbers and press "Aktar" button, then I want to add to listbox like below but how can I do that

I want to get a result like below

[image]

Comment: Is it a webform or window form i.e. for webapplication or window application?

Comment: For webform or winform, use toolbox at left side in Visual studio - https://www.guru99.com/asp-net-controls.html

Comment: @Ajay2707 a window form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding numbers from start number to end number to ListBox:

```
private void btnAktar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    var a = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    var b = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    var s = string.Empty;
    for (var x=a;x<=b;x++)
    {
        s += x.ToString();
        listBox1.Items.Add(s);
    }
    var chars = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(chars);
    var reversedS = new string(chars);
    for(var i = 1; i < reversedS.Length; i++)
    {
        var item = reversedS.Substring(i, reversedS.Length - i);
        listBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: oh, thank you for all helping but i have a question. your answer "1234 - 4321" but i need "1234 - 321".

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8w3E.png)

Comment: i edited my answer :)  if this solution worked for you, please mark it as the answer